# Library Locations - Linux

Tags: c++, linux, static-libraries

I have an SFML application I would like to compile it for Windows from Linux. Up until now, I've compiled with `g++` and `-lsmfl-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

Now I've installed **g++-mingw-w64-x86-64** and I have to compile with `'/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++'`

Now it says `SFML/.../...hpp: No such file or directory`

I read that I need to give it the location of the `.so` files of the library.

I've never seen those, where are those typically? SFML is installed in `/usr/local/include/SFML`

`-L'/location???'`

Answer (score 1):

`L'/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'`

`L` provides the search directory where the .so files are located.
The SFML .so files just happen to be in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Then you use your library flags normally

`-lsfml-...`

Answer (score 0):

- -I: path to header file *.h, *.hpp (i upper)
- -L: path to library (*.so *.a)
- -l: library name  (L lower)

  g++ -I /path/to/header -lmylib -L /path/to/library

**Now it says SFML/.../...hpp: No such file or directory**

compile error because header file not found.  fix it first.